# Connecting to Data Sources in the Script Task

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

I'm having some trouble using the connection manager from a script task in SSIS. The program will compile perfectly until I try using the connection that is set in the Environment.

```
Private Sub InsertLog(ByRef log() As String)
        Dim conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection
        conn = _
            DirectCast(Dts.Connections("ConfigDB").AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction),  _
            SqlClient.SqlConnection)
        MsgBox(log(0) & "  " & log(1) & "  " & log(2) & "  " & log(3) & Dts.Connections("ConfigDB").ConnectionString.ToString())
End Sub
```

If I comment out the Dim and DirectCast the package executes successfully and I can successfully get the connection string in a messagebox.

```
Data Source=PathToServer;Initial Catalog=DB;Provider=...;Integrated Security=...;Application Name=...;Auto Translate=False;
```

Has anyone else had this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution. The reason why it failed was because of the Provider and Auto Translate, so my solution is to strip out what is not needed.

```
Dim strConnection As String = Dts.Connections("Automation").ConnectionString.ToString()
        Dim regProvider As New Regex("Provider=([^;]*);")
        Dim regTranslate As New Regex("Auto Translate=([^;]*);")
        strConnection = regProvider.Replace(strConnection, "")
        strConnection = regTranslate.Replace(strConnection, "")
        Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConnection)
```